# Kafka Avro serializer, Ignoring serialization exception

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

I am using kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.0.jar. When I hit exceptions deserializing events my consumer stops and does not move to the next event. These are usually caused by errors at the producer and have happened because of issues using a new avro schema registry server.

Example:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 58
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

I can fix the exceptions, that's not the issue. But to fix the consumers I need to reset each offset manually to latest. This is a lot of hassle in my scenario and I have a lot of consumer groups.

Is there a way for me to ignore these exceptions and move the offset at the consumer? I guess because I am using manual offset commit I have this issue.  Anyone knows of ways to configure kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.0.jar to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have mainly two options:

1. Override the deserializer `deserialize` method and reimplement it by catching the `ClassCastException` exception and returning a `null` Object instead of the deserialized record. These `null` objects will then be dealt with in your consumer code.
2. Catch the `SerializationException` exception on your consumer code and `seek` your consumer past the bad record offset.

Both solutions are very well explained in [this article](https://jonboulineau.me/blog/kafka/dealing-with-bad-records-in-kafka) by Jon Boulineau.